# WCF serialization of decimal to string with 2 decimal precision

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, code-generation, partial-classes

We are connecting to an external system that provides a WSDL that expects decimals to be provided to 2 decimal places - i.e.:

```xml
<collectionAmount>1000.00</collectionAmount>
```

However, when our client serializes the SOAP request the decimals appear with a single precision:

```xml
<collectionAmount>1000.0</collectionAmount>
```

We have attempted to use metadata extension:

```cs
    [MetadataType(typeof(amountSetRequestMetadata))]
    public partial class amountSetRequest
    {
        internal sealed class amountSetRequestMetadata
        {
            [XmlIgnore]
            public decimal collectionAmount { get; set; }

            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 14, ElementName = "collectionAmount")]
            public string collectionAmountString => "yay!";
        }
    }
```

`amountSetRequest` is the generated partial class that the WSDL service auto-generator produces. The output XML is no different so this doesn't appear to have any effect on the request.

We would think that this is fairly common, but can't find out much how this is solved. We have seen solutions that extend the base XML serializer.

What is this cleanest way to have a SOAP request serialized in this way?

Comment: Apparently, for XML proper, there's a way to specify this in an XML configuration file. See [this](https://www.obj-sys.com/docs/xbv25/CCppUsersGuide/ch06s03.html). However, it's very hard to google relevant information about this because google invariably thinks you are talking about a regular configuration file, stored as XML, and not a configuration of the XML format itself. So I've not been able to figure out if/how this can be applied to SOAP messages. Good luck!

Comment: You would need a number format like ToString("F2")

Comment: @jdweng yes, that would be the ideal - however - the contract accepts `decimal` not `string` so the internal XML serialization is not converting it properly. The question is how to get that to do the serialization according to the expectation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we fixed it by slightly hacking the type-system.

It turns out that decimals converted from strings and back to decimals have different precisions. Hence we did:

```cs
public void RequestAmount(decimal amount) {
   var request = new amountSetRequest()
   request.collectionAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(amount.ToString("F2"));
   // ...
}
```

In doing this when the XML serializer sees the decimal, it keeps the precision that the `Convert.ToDecimal` uses from `ToString`.

Answer (score 0):

Use following :

```
    public partial class amountSetRequest
    {
        private decimal _collectionAmount { get; set; }

        public string collectionAmount {
            get {return _collectionAmount.ToString("F2");}
            set {_collectionAmount = decimal.Parse(value);}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Compiler fails with `collectionAmount` already defined. The initial partial class is auto generated from the wsdl so `collectionAmount` is already part of the class so can't change it's contract to a `string`

Comment: It doesn't need to be a partial class (nor metadata extension).  Put code in main part of class.

Comment: If the wsdl file changes, we will generate a new file. Another team having to support hand-crafted changes after auto-generation leads to problems. Hence we are looking for ways of achieving the serialization without changing the auto generated code.

Comment: I don't think you can do it.  You would need to inherit (and then override) the class and then the xml would need a type attribute.  The best that I could suggest is to use conditional compile statements so it is obvious what was manually changed.